# Warning: Unresolved attribute reference 'all' for class 'list'

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

When I was creating this simple function with numpy library imported, I got a warning from PyCharm: *Unresolved attribute reference 'all' for class 'list'*

```
import numpy as np
def func():
    b1 = [True, False, False]
    b2 = [True, True, True]
    return b1.all() and b2.all()
```

Then I changed `return b1.all() and b2.all()` to `return np.all(b1) and np.all(b2)` and the warning is gone.
Can anyone explain why this warning appears, please?

Comment: did u try `all(b1)`? `all` is builtin method, and there is no attribute named `all` for list like pandas series.

Comment: `list` doesn't have a method `all`. There is a builtin `all(b1) and all(b2)` you could use instead. Numpy does have an all method as well, which is why that "fixed" your problem.

Comment: `np.all(alist)` in effect does `np.array(alist).all()`.  It converts the argument to an array, and then applies the method. `AttributeError` means you either got the object wrong or the method wrong.  `list` does not have that method (reread the basic Python docs if needed).

Comment: Thanks, I know the reason now from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```py
In [58]: def func():
    ...:     b1 = [True, False, False]
    ...:     b2 = [True, True, True]
    ...:     return all(b1) and all(b2)
    ...:

In [59]: func()
Out[59]: False
```

Numpy also has an `all` function you can use, but it seems overkill for this problem to import numpy just to use it.

Comment: I also want to ask you about the boolean narray situation similar to that question. I have is function: 
```def is_greyscale_img(np_img):
    b1 = np_img[..., 0] == np_img[..., 1]
    b2 = np_img[..., 1] == np_img[..., 2]
    return b1.all() and b1.all()```
where np_img is 3d array and the warning is similar: _Unresolved attribute reference 'all' for class 'bool'_. b1 and b2 are supposed to be boolean 3d arrays, not boolean. Can you explain why this warning pops up in this case?

Comment: Are you sure it is? Check `type(np_img[..., 0])`

Comment: Yes, I am.
```b1 = np_img[..., 0] == np_img[..., 1]
    print(type(np_img[..., 0]))
    print(type(b1))```
Console:
```<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>```